# function to create a dynamic nav list in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am not understanding this function(section).  How does the section.classname and section.id work?

```js
const navElements = document.querySelectorAll('section')
const navBar = document.getElementById('navbar__list')


navElements.forEach(function(section){
 const navlistElement = `<li class='menu__link ${section.className}' data-link=${section.id}><a href="#${section.id}">${section.dataset.nav}</li>`
 navBar.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',navlistElement)
})
```

Comment: The id and class of the element? Are you asking what they are or are you asking how the string template literal works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have figured it out!